# Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - `No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection'

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecr

When trying to connect AWS ECR from Ubuntu supportive Ec2 machine (I need to use docker pull for downloading image from AWS ECR), I am getting below error. How to solve this issue?

> Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection' on object at path /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login`

[image]

Comment: After executing this command, the issue is still persists.    "$sudo apt install gnupg2 pass "

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We're seeing the same error.